# Как правильно вести отладку WPF приложения?

Tags: c#, wpf

Собственно вопрос, как правильно вести отладку WPF приложения?

Например, привязки, которые не работают.

Ведь WPF просто схавывает все и не выдает никаких ошибок. А потом смотришь во WM и видишь, что где-то свойство забыл сделать публичным и все такое.

Comment: А у вас студия разве не пишет ошибок видимости полей и методов?

Comment: А где она такое должна писать? При работе с XAML?

Comment: В XAML тоже имеется проверка не только синтаксиса, но доступности переменных. Хотя да, бинды на локальные переменные не подсвечивает.

Comment: Ошибки привязок пишутся в debug output окно

Answer (score 10):

Для отладки привязанных данных достаточно выбрать соответствующий уровень в настройках студии.

[image: Settings]

- Заходим по пути `Средства` - `Параметры` - `Отладка` - `Окно вывода`.
- Меняем значение пункта `Привязка данных` на тот, который нам нужен, я лично ставлю `Предупреждение`.
- Все, теперь при ошибке привязки данных мы будем получать в окне логирования что то на подобии этого (где сразу видно, что программа не нашла в `MainViewModel` свойства `CloseCommand`:

> System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error:
>    'CloseCommand' property not found on 'object' ''MainViewModel'
>    (HashCode=46793998)'. BindingExpression:Path=CloseCommand;
>    DataItem='MainViewModel' (HashCode=46793998); target element is
>    'Button' (Name=''); target property is 'Command' (type 'ICommand')

Для отладки, этого вполне достаточно, но можно пойти дальше - ReSharper. У него есть уже из коробки подсветка всего необходимого прям в XAML разметке (что тоже очень хорошо помогает в разработке)

[image: ReSharper]

Но тут нужно указать `DataContext` для дизайнера, что бы студия и ReSharper знали от куда брать эти свойства. Делается это путем добавления строки, примерно такого содержания:

```
d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance {x:Type main:MainViewModel}}"
```

Comment: Спасибо, я тоже взял на заметку! Хоть и давно пользуюсь ReSharper

Comment: А отладка всяких триггеров например? Или с ними не должно возникать проблем.

Comment: @iluxa1810 Если это какой нибудь DataTrigger, где идет привязка к созданному нами свойству, то там все тоже, что и выше, если другие триггеры, то при запуске программа скорей всего попросту не запустится, указав точные "координаты" проблемного места. Так что да, проблем именно с триггерами возникнуть не должна. Главное в XAML это привязка и синтаксис, с привязкой я вам помог, а синтаксис сама студия укажет вам на ошибку.

Comment: Решарпер часто, кстати, не видит привязанные данные. Особенно если свойство DataContext явно не задано нигде