# Не отображаются строки у DataGrid Которая располагается в TabControl

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, datagrid, tabcontrol

Имеется окно, в котором располагается TabControl, в котором на каждой вкладке должна быть DataGrid. Проблема в том, что если DataGrid располагается не в TabControl, то данные и строчки отображаются, но как только я переношу эту DataGrid в TabControl, отображаются только наименования колонок, а самих данных нет. 
Как это можно исправить?

Сам проект выложил по этой [ссылке](https://yadi.sk/d/bYO1M9jSUyBZbQ).

Заранее благодарю!)

Главное окно:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp3.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp3"
    xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:WpfApp3.ViewModel"

    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
<Window.DataContext>
    <vm:MainWindowViewModel/>
</Window.DataContext>
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="100" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="10" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="10" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Grid
        Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1">
        <StackPanel>
            <Button
                Margin="0,0,0,10"
                Content="Add"
                Command="{Binding AddTab}"

                Height="30" Width="80"
                VerticalAlignment="Top" />

            <!--<Button
                Content="Remove"
                Command="{Binding RemoveTab}"
                Height="30" Width="80"
                VerticalAlignment="Top" />-->
        </StackPanel>

    </Grid>

    <TabControl
        TabStripPlacement="Top"
        SelectedIndex="{Binding Selected}" 
        ItemsSource="{Binding Titles, Mode=TwoWay}"
        Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1">

        <TabControl.ItemTemplate >
            <DataTemplate>
                <DockPanel>
                    <Button Name="btnDelete" Height="15" Width="15" DockPanel.Dock="Right" 
                            Margin="5,0,0,0" Padding="0" 
                            Command="{Binding RemTab}">
                        <Button.Template>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                                <Border x:Name="Bd" Background="Transparent">
                                    <Path x:Name="Pt" Data="M0,0 M0.2,0.2 L 0.8,0.8 M0.2,0.8 L0.8,0.2 M1,1"
                                          Stretch="Uniform" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="2"/>
                                </Border>
                                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                        <Setter TargetName="Bd" Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
                                        <Setter TargetName="Pt" Property="Stroke" Value="White"/>
                                    </Trigger>
                                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Button.Template>
                    </Button>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Header}" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                </DockPanel>

            </DataTemplate>

        </TabControl.ItemTemplate>

        <TabControl.ContentTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding ParamLists}"
                          AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                          CanUserAddRows="True"
                          IsReadOnly="False">
                    <DataGrid.Columns>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Parameter Name" Binding="{Binding ParamName}"/>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Prefix" Width="100" Binding="{Binding Prefix}"/>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Suffix" Width="100" Binding="{Binding Suffix}"/>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Find in value" Width="100" Binding="{Binding FindValue}"/>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Replace" Width="100" Binding="{Binding ReplaceValue}"/>
                    </DataGrid.Columns>
                </DataGrid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </TabControl.ContentTemplate>
    </TabControl>


</Grid>
```

MainVindowViewModel:

```
public class MainWindowViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    #region Field
    static int tabs = 1;
    private ICommand _addTab;
    private ICommand _removeTab;
    private ObservableCollection<Item> _titles;
    private ObservableCollection<ParamList> _paramLists;
    private int _selected;
    #endregion

    #region Properties
    public int Selected
    {
        get { return _selected; }
        set
        {
            _selected = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Selected");
        }
    }

    public ObservableCollection<Item> Titles
    {
        get { return _titles; }
        set
        {
            _titles = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Titles");
        }
    }

    public ObservableCollection<ParamList> ParamLists
    {
        get => _paramLists;
        set
        {
            _paramLists = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("ParamLists");
        }
    }


    #endregion

    #region Public Methods



    #endregion


    #region Private Methods
    private void RemoveTabItem()
    {
        int selected = Selected;
        Titles.RemoveAt(selected);
        tabs--;
    }

    private void AddTabItem()
    {
        var header = "Tab " + tabs;
        var remTab = RemoveTab;
        var item = new Item { Header = header, RemTab = remTab };
        Titles.Add(item);
        tabs++;
        OnPropertyChanged("Titles");
    }



    #endregion

    #region MVVM
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    #endregion

    #region Constructors
    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        Titles = new ObservableCollection<Item>();

        //ParamLists.Add(new ParamList{ParamName = "", Prefix = "", Suffix = "", FindValue = "", ReplaceValue = ""});
        _paramLists = new ObservableCollection<ParamList>();
        _paramLists.Add(new ParamList { FindValue = "ss", Suffix = "x", Prefix = "dwef", ReplaceValue = "fe", ParamName = "gr" });

        Titles.Add(new Item { Header = "Default", RemTab = RemoveTab }); // По умолчанию одна вкладка
    }



    #endregion

    #region Commands
    public ICommand AddTab
    {
        get
        {
            return _addTab ?? (_addTab = new RelayCommand(
               x =>
               {
                   AddTabItem();
               }));
        }
    }
    public ICommand RemoveTab
    {
        get
        {
            return _removeTab ?? (_removeTab = new RelayCommand(
               x =>
               {
                   RemoveTabItem();
               }));
        }
    }
    #endregion

    #region Classes
    public class Item
    {
        public string Header { get; set; }
        public ICommand RemTab { get; set; }
    }
    public class ParamList
    {
        public string ParamName { get; set; }
        public string Prefix { get; set; }
        public string Suffix { get; set; }
        public string FindValue { get; set; }
        public string ReplaceValue { get; set; }
    }
    #endregion




}
```

Comment: Посмотрите как производить отладку WPF ([например тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/874490/220553)), вы тогда наверно поняли бы, что если ваш `DataGrid` задается как стиль `TabControl`, то `DataGrid` будет искать данные внутри `ItemsSource` заданного для `TabControl`. То есть ваш `ParamLists` должен быть в `Titles[0].ParamLists` для такой привязки.

Comment: Получилось, спасибо