# Привязка значения свойства стиля к элементам пользовательского шаблона внутри стиля

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding

Пытаюсь сделать стиль для CheckBox'а с границами разного цвета. Но, не понимаю, почему не работает привязка значения Setter'а (BorderThickness) к Rectangle (Width и Height) для масштабирования толщины границ через свойство BorderThickness у CheckBox'а.

XAML:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="CheckBoxStyle1" TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}">
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="#5333"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}">
                    <Grid x:Name="templateRoot" Background="Transparent" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                        <DockPanel x:Name="checkBoxBorder" LastChildFill="False" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                            <Rectangle Fill="Yellow" DockPanel.Dock="Left" Width="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"/>
                            <Rectangle Fill="Red" DockPanel.Dock="Top" Height="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"/>                                
                            <Rectangle Fill="Green" DockPanel.Dock="Right" Width="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"/>
                            <Rectangle Fill="Blue" DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" Height="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"/>
                        </DockPanel>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid Background="#5777">
    <CheckBox Width="200" Height="200" Style="{DynamicResource CheckBoxStyle1}" BorderThickness="5"/>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Во-первых используйте Border, а не Rectangle, во-вторых, как вы поняли, что не работает?

Comment: Научитесь использовать и понимать [отладку](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/874490/220553) XAML (правда с шаблонами она редко когда помогает)). Ну а так, попробуйте в C# коде написать следующее `new Rectangle().Width = new CheckBox().BorderThickness`, что увидите? Думаю сразу поймете в чем вы накосячили... И да, как сказали выше, вы делаете костыль, ибо за бордюр в WPF отвечает `Border`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`TemplateBinding` здесь не работает, я не разбирался, почему. Но самое главное - вы пытаетесь свойство `Width` типа `double` привязать к свойству `BorderThickness` типа `Thickness`. Не находите это странным?

Ну и Rectangle здесь не к месту.

```xml
<Style x:Key="CheckBoxStyle1" TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}">
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#5333"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}">
                <Grid Background="Transparent" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                    <DockPanel LastChildFill="False" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                        <Border Background="Yellow" DockPanel.Dock="Left" Width="{Binding BorderThickness.Left, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=CheckBox}}"/>
                        <Border Background="Red" DockPanel.Dock="Top" Height="{Binding BorderThickness.Top, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=CheckBox}}"/>
                        <Border Background="Green" DockPanel.Dock="Right" Width="{Binding BorderThickness.Right, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=CheckBox}}"/>
                        <Border Background="Blue" DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" Height="{Binding BorderThickness.Left, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=CheckBox}}"/>
                    </DockPanel>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

```xml
<CheckBox Width="200" Height="200" Style="{StaticResource CheckBoxStyle1}" BorderThickness="5"/>
```

Comment: А смысл тут делать несколько бордеров, когда спокойно с этим справиться один? Если как "переписал код из вопроса и на сделал на его примере", то тогда наверно стоит показать еще как "должно быть"? Тут же ведь можно все в `ControlTemplate` выкинуть, оставив просто `<Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" />`, ну и цвет рамки еще (если надо).

Comment: @EvgeniyZ у него 4 разных бордера разных цветов, каждый прибит докпанелью к своей стороне прямоугольника. Я не умею красить один в 4 цвета. В любом случае, я не пошел далеко искать идеальное решение, оно наверняка есть, просто сделал так, чтобы вариант автора заработал.