# обновление изображения из дочерней панели wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Не могу обновить изображение через MVVM.

WPF изучаю от силы 4 дня.

Часть кода формы:

```
<Ellipse Height="200" Width="200" Margin="8,10,8,349">
<Ellipse.Fill>
    <ImageBrush x:Name="usprof" Stretch="UniformToFill" ImageSource="{Binding CurrentAvatar}"/>
</Ellipse.Fill>
```

MVVM:

```
public RelayCommand ChangeAvatarCommand { get; set; }

 private object? _currentAvatar;
 public object? CurrentAvatar
 {
     get { return _currentAvatar; }
     set { _currentAvatar = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
 }

 public MainViewModel() 
 {
     ChangeAvatarCommand = new RelayCommand(o =>
     {
         CurrentAvatar = UserData.AvatarPath; // Код срабатывает, но изображение не меняется
     });
 }
```

UPD:

Если необходимо, то вот код кнопки из другой панели:

```
<Button x:Name="selectBtn" Command="{Binding ChangeAvatarCommand}" Click="selectBtn_Click" Content="Select" VerticalAlignment="Center" Foreground="White" FontSize="15" Margin="10 0 0 0" Width="100" BorderThickness="0" Style="{StaticResource stdButton}"/>
```

Также в отдельном `StackPanel`

Выбор изображения по кнопке:

```
OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
ofd.Filter = "PNG files(*.png)|*.png|JPG files(*.jpg)|*.jpg|All files(*.*)|*.*";
if (ofd.ShowDialog().Value)
{
    avatarPath.Text = ofd.FileName;
    UserData.AvatarPath = ofd.FileName;
}
```

`OnPropertyChanged`:

```
public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string? name = null)
{
    PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
}
```

`RelayCommand`:

```
class RelayCommand : ICommand
{
    private Action<object> _execute;
    private Func<object, bool> _canExecute;

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
    {
        add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
        remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
    }

    public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute, Func<object, bool> canExecute = null)
    {
        _execute = execute;
        _canExecute = canExecute;
    }

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter) 
    {
        return _canExecute == null || _canExecute(parameter);
    }

    public void Execute(object parameter) { _execute(parameter); }
}
```

Comment: "Обновляется", то есть сначала она стоит и все ок? И что значит "из дочерней панели"? Ну а так, если выполняется и там все ок, то занимайтесь [отладкой](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/874490/220553) XAML, смотрите что ему конкретно не нравиться (если такое есть), ну а если там все ок, значит всеж вы ошибаетесь, и утверждение "код срабатывает" ошибочно. По тому, что показано в вопросе, все хорошо, а это значит, что вы нам что-то не договариваете (например `Ellipse` может лежит внутри `ListBox`).

Comment: В начале всё ок, да.
У меня стоит свап панелей через mvvm, и на одной из них- кнопка выбора изображения.
P.S. `Ellipse` в `StackPanel`

Comment: В XAML тоже всё отлично.

Comment: OnPropertyChanged покажите, что за обработчик события на кнопке, что он делает?

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/mWWavwP
В обработчике- смена `UserData.AvatarPath`
P.S. В теме код

Comment: Делайте тогда самодостаточный пример, который мы можем запустить у себя и выяснить в чем проблема. Пока я лишь могу заметить 2 вещи: 1. У вас кнопка делает и клик, и команду, что не правильно. 2. У вас нарушение MVVM, ибо ваш View слой вдруг знает про ViewModel, ну или наоборот (я не знаю где этот код `OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();`), если наоборот, то ViewModel не должна открывать окна, даже диалоговые, ибо окно это View.

Answer (score 0):

Оказывается, мое приложение просто не вызывало событие обновления изображения (решил костылём).
Спасибо большое Евгению за информацию.

Костыль:

```
private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    username.Text = UserData.Login;
    Task.Run(() => 
    {
        string pathNow = string.Empty;
        while (true)
        {
            if (pathNow != UserData.AvatarPath)
            {
                pathNow = UserData.AvatarPath;
                ChangePic();
            }

            Thread.Sleep(150);
        }
    });
}

private void ChangePic()
{
    if (UserData.AvatarPath != string.Empty)
    {
        Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() => usprof.ImageSource = new BitmapImage(new Uri(UserData.AvatarPath, UriKind.Relative))));
    }
    else { Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() => usprof.ImageSource = new BitmapImage(new Uri("pack://application:,,,/Resources/avatar.png")))); }
}
```

В итоге MVVM можно отложить...
То еще Г, но всё же.

Ссылка на пример: https://mega.nz/file/l6oizZTJ#26vag4RcjkuYbFuOQDw85q5d9m3PXyrPKOTkddRYJ5w

Comment: Еще раз повторю, сделайте **самодостаточный пример**, вот возьмите чистый WPF проект, напишите там то, что у вас, без лишних классов, методов и прочего, одно свойство и его изменение, и прикрепите к вопросу этот чистый код, мы посмотрим и скажем как правильно. В ответе вы написали действительно непонятную кашу, когда как у вас должна успешно работать привязка, но раз не работает, вы ее где-то ломаете, но мы не можем сказать где, ибо вы нам это место не показываете. Так что, пример, мы у себя воспроизводим - даем рекомендации, готово.

Comment: Ссылка на проект: https://mega.nz/file/l6oizZTJ#26vag4RcjkuYbFuOQDw85q5d9m3PXyrPKOTkddRYJ5w

Comment: Когда пишете человеку, указывайте его ник через `@`, иначе он не увидит уведомление. Я сейчас ваш вопрос увидел лишь благодаря правки, когда вы мне 3 дня назад дали ссылку... Посмотрел я ваш проект, там многое не так, если брать именно обновления изображения, то ваша проблема в постоянном `<viewmodel:MainViewModel/>`, что является [нарушением MVVM](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/562586/220553). Смотрите, когда вы пишете `<ЧтоТо.DataContext><...></..>`, то это аналогично написанию `this.DataContext = new ...();`, ключевое тут `new`, то есть вы **каждый** раз создаете новый `MainViewModel`

Comment: А теперь простая логика, вот у вас две корзинки на столе, обе одинакового размера, одинаковой формы, цвета, и так далее. В одну вы положили яблоко, в другой это яблоко появится? Нет. А если вы положите в обе корзинки по яблоку, а после откусите у одного яблока, это изменения будет в другой? Нет. Ок, если вы напишете `var c1 = new Class(); var c2 = new Class();` а потом сделаете `c1.Value = 123;`, в классе 2 будет `Value == 123`? Нет, ибо это два разных экземпляра класса. Я надеюсь вы поняли к чему я клоню? У вас вообще не должно быть `<ЧтоТо.DataContext>`, он должен задаваться автоматически.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ да, я вас понял. Большое спасибо.
Иными словами, мне необходимо работать в `c1`.

Comment: Не совсем так, как вы это себе понимаете) Ваша задача сейчас, не создавать повторно MainViewModel, а использовать на нее ссылку, либо перейти в XAML на уровень выше и взять `DataContext` родителя, от которого получать уже команду. То есть, у вас должно быть **либо** слой  `ConfigViewModel`, в котором есть ссылка на `MainViewModel` и в XAML вы делаете `{Binding MainVM.ChangeAvatarCommand}`, **либо** переписывает XAML, и ищете там предка, например, так `Command="{Binding DataContext.ChangeAvatarCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window }}"`.